# Archivo js en servidor vpn

Tags: nodejs, laravel-5, angular4

Tengo un dilema , estoy trabajando un char con sokect.io este es mi .js

```
let express = require('express')
let app = express();

let http = require('http');
let server = http.Server(app);

let socketIO = require('socket.io');
let io = socketIO(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected',socket.id);
   // io.emit('new_message',socket.id);


    socket.on('new_message', (message) => {
            io.emit('new_message',message);
            //socket.broadcast.to(message).emit('new_message',message);
            console.log( 'el mensaje emitido '+message);
        });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

todo fino por que lo ejecuto en el terminal asi node index.js
y queda escuchando en el puerto 3000 ..

Ahora mi dilema es como lo subo al servidor y que ruta seria en la cual estaria escuchando ?????

Answer (score 0):

Obviamente quedará escuchando en:

> [ip del servidor]:3000

Debes asegurarte de abrir el puerto `3000` como TCP para inbound y outbound, de otra manera no será posible el intercambio de tráfico con los clientes.

Comment: voy a ver que tal , gracias amigo